# Using .add(String) for arrayList <Book>

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a school project in which i need to read in book numbers and title from a .txt file and put them into an arrayList , Heres what I have thus far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.util.*;


ArrayList <Book> Books = new ArrayList <Book> ();


public class Books{

String referenceNumber, title;

Books(String _referenceNumber, String _title){
    referenceNumber = _referenceNumber;
    title = _title;
   }
}
```

Above is the necessary imports, the array and the class that defines what a book consists of. Below is the method in which it will read the text from the file and put it into the array, My problem is that im not sure what to use in place of .add(string) (where it says "Books.add(title);" as it will not work for me..

```
private void LoadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BookList.txt"));
    String title;
    while ((title = br.readLine()) != null){
        Books.add(title);
    }
    } catch (IOException e){
} finally {
    try{
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ex){
    }
}
String [] bookList = new String[Books.size()];
title.toArray(bookList);
}


Thanks for any help you can provide, I am a beginner to this and will appreciate any advice
```

Comment: Check where your `Books` variable is declared. Is it allowed there?

Comment: books.add(new Book(number,title)); To retreive: thetitle = books.get(i).title;

Comment: Did you mean `public class Book`, singular?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...
String title = null;
String referenceNumber = null;
while ((title = br.readLine()) != null){
    referenceNumber = br.readLine();

    Books.add(new Book(referenceNumber,title));
}
...
```

Your text file will look like

```
1
The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
2
Huckleberry Finn
4
The Sword in the Stone
```

---

--EDIT--

change class declaration

```
public class Book{

   String referenceNumber, title;

   public Book(String _referenceNumber, String _title){
        referenceNumber = _referenceNumber;
        title = _title;
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried that now I am getting the following error:

Cannot find symbol: variable referenceNumber | 
Cannot find symbol: variable title |

internal error; cannot instantiate java.awt.print.Book.<init> at java.awt.print.Book to ()

any suggestions?

Comment: read comments carefully. Can you tell me how the line is shown in your text file.

Comment: I have updated my post. Correct me if I have taken it in wrong way for text file.

Comment: Sorry let me update it in my post. You have to change the class name from Books to Book. I have updated it in my post.

Comment: Try to analyze it. We are not here to resolve each and every error. Its a compilation error. If your are using an Eclipse IDE then it clearly tell you where is the error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayList **Books** is of type **java.awt.print.Book** and it can hold only values of that type. So you cannot add a string to the Arraylist. You have to either change the type of the Arraylist to a String or add an object of type Book to the Arraylist.